# The most efficient way to trim a file name in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, file, ecmascript-6, trim

I was wondering how to trim a file name in JS to show "..." or any appendix for that matter after a certain number of characters, the most efficient way to handle all possible test cases.

**Rules**

1. Show the actual file extension and not the last character after splitting the string name with "."
2. The function should take the input file name (string), the number of characters to trim (integer) and appendix (string) as the parameter.
3. By efficient, I mean I expect to write fewer lines of code and handle all possible edge cases.

**Sample Inputs**

1. myAwesomeFile.min.css
2. my Awesome File.tar.gz
3. file.png

**Expected output** (say I want to trim after 5 characters)

1. myAwe....min.css
2. my Aw....tar.gz
3. file.png

**Editing the question to show my attempt**

```js
function trimFileName(str, noOfChars, appendix) {
  let nameArray = str.split(".");
  let fileType = `.${nameArray.pop()}`;
  let fileName = nameArray.join(" ");

  if (fileName.length >= noOfChars) {
    fileName = fileName.substr(0, noOfChars) + appendix;
  };

  return (fileName + fileType);
}

console.log(trimFileName("myAwesomeFile.min.css", 5, "..."));
console.log(trimFileName("my Awesome File.tar.gz", 5, "..."));
console.log(trimFileName("file.png", 5, "..."));
```

**Edit #2:** Feel free to go ahead and edit the question if you think it's not the standard expectation and add more edge cases to the sample inputs and expected outputs.

**Edit #3:** Added a few more details to the question after the new comments. I know my attempt doesn't fulfill my expected outputs (and I am unsure whether the output I have listed above is a standard expectation or not).

**Edit #4 (Final):** Removed the rule of not breaking a word in the middle after a continuous backlash in the comments and changed the rules to cater to more realistic and practical use cases.

Comment: Why is number 2 unchanged? And why is number 3 shortened after two (or three, with the dot) characters?

Comment: Why is `jumps_over` preserved in the second case, but not the fourth?

Comment: Do you want to split the file name form it's extension?

Comment: You have a lot of cases and not even a single lick of an attempt to accomplish one of them? Not to mention you're looking for the most efficient way, when you haven't showed us what you tried yet.

Comment: This is really unclear what you're tryin to do... the expected output is unconsistent and does not match the description of "I want to trim after 5 chars" at all. Please give concrete examples and showus what you've tried

Comment: I feel unless there is a white-space character, the file name should be treated as one word. ***Remember:*** the no breaking a word in the middle rule. I think this is how it should be. Feel free to go ahead and edit the question if you think it's not the standard expectation.

Comment: By what metric do you measure "most efficient"?

Comment: What code have you tried?  This is really just rote string processing.  There aren't any magic shortcuts.  Decide what algorithm you want to use for deciding where you want to break into a `...` and write the code to implement that algorithm.  Also, most trim operations like this give themselves a max number of characters they will allow to remain unbroken because typically, the whole point of doing this is to fit some abbreviated representation of the string into a pre-defined space.  So, in your #2 case, if you don't break it at all, it kind of defeats the typical purpose.

Comment: I was planning to add my attempt as an answer to this thread. I have stared this thread because I have seen answers on string trimming but nothing answers how to efficiently (by efficiently I mean handling all possible edge cases without writing many lines of code) achieve this.

Comment: `fileType = \`.${nameArray.pop()}\``this seems wrong. It expects the *last* thing after a dot to be the file extension. `myfile.tar.gz` has the extension `.tar.gz`, not `.gz`. Similarly, the *name* of the file is `myfile` not `myfile.tar`.

Comment: I'm still not clear on what the rules of the contraction are. What is considered "a word" for the algorithm to avoid breaking into parts? What happens if you do stop within a word - do you show the entire thing or hide it? Does it depend on the position? It *seems* like you want to show the entire word if it's the first word in a name, but hide it if it's the second one. But what happens if it's the third one? `my.w.another_word`? Also, do you want *actual* file extension checking or only close enough (`.tar.gz` is treated as if it's `.tar`?

Comment: @SibasishMohanty In the (near?) future this could be achieved with a simple CSS, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow . Using string value it'll be easy to cut text in the middle of it, only that it's almost provides the use of inline styles instead of a stylesheet.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys! I have added a few more examples to clarify what I am trying to achieve. I hope it helps.

Comment: FrameChallenge: What do you want this for? If you have limited space for displaying a filename - the actual length of the printed string will be different depending on characters ("iiiii" will be shorter than "ww") - and you will need a different amount of characters depending on the size of the extension. What is your real-world requirement ?

Comment: @Falco thanks for the suggestion. Kindly update the question to fit most of the real-world requirements. I was making my own file uploader component and stumbled upon this problem. I thought this is the ideal requirement but I may be wrong since no one here thinks so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we treat the dot character `.` as a separator for file extensions, what you ask for can be solved with a single line of JavaScript:

```js
name.replace(new RegExp('(^[^\\.]{' + chars + '})[^\\.]+'), '$1' + subst);
```

Demo code in the following snippet:

```js
function f(name, chars, subst) {
  return name.replace(
    new RegExp('(^[^\\.]{' + chars + '})[^\\.]+'), '$1' + subst);
}


test('myAwesomeFile.min.css', 5, '...', 'myAwe....min.css');
test('my Awesome File.tar.gz', 5, '...', 'my Aw....tar.gz');
test('file.png', 5, '...', 'file.png');

function test(filename, length, subst, expected) {
  let actual = f(filename, length, subst);
  console.log(actual, actual === expected ? 'OK' : 'expected: ' + expected);
}
```

On Windows, AFAIK, the file extension is only what follows the last dot. Thus, technically, the file extension of `"myAwesomeFile.min.css"` is just `css`, and the file extension of `"my Awesome File.tar.gz"` is just `gz`.

In this case, what you ask for can still be solved with one line of JavaScript:

```js
name.replace(new RegExp('(^.{' + chars + '}).+(\\.[^\\.]*$)'), '$1' + subst + '$2');
```

Demo code in the following snippet:

```js
function f(name, chars, subst) {
  return name.replace(
    new RegExp('(^.{' + chars + '}).+(\\.[^\\.]*$)'), '$1' + subst + '$2');
}


test('myAwesomeFile.min.css', 5, '...', 'myAwe....css');
test('my Awesome File.tar.gz', 5, '...', 'my Aw....gz');
test('file.png', 5, '...', 'file.png');

function test(filename, length, subst, expected) {
  let actual = f(filename, length, subst);
  console.log(actual, actual === expected ? 'OK' : 'expected: ' + expected);
}
```

If you really want to allow edge cases with specific multiple extensions, you probably need to define a comprehensive list of all allowed multiple extensions to know how to deal with cases like `"my.awesome.file.min.css"`. You would need to provide a list of all cases you want to include before it would be possible to determine how efficient any solution could be.

Answer (score 3):

It is really hard to account for all extensions (including edge cases). See this list for example for common extensions: https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001789.htm. Event with that many extensions, the list is exhaustive of all extensions.

Your function is OK but to account for more cases it could be re-written to this:

```js
function trimFileName(filename, limit = 5, spacer = '.') {
  const split = filename.indexOf(".");
  const name = filename.substring(0, split);
  const ext = filename.substring(split);

  let trimName = name.substring(0, limit);

  if (name.length > trimName.length)
    trimName = trimName.padEnd(limit + 3, spacer);

  return trimName + ext;
}

console.log(trimFileName("myAwesomeFile.min.css"));
console.log(trimFileName("my Awesome File.tar.gz"));
console.log(trimFileName("file.png"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Below is a pretty simple approach to achieve shortening in the fashion you desire. Comments are in the code, but let me know if anything needs additional explanation:

```js
//A simple object to hold some configs about how we want to shorten the file names
const config = {
  charsBeforeTrim: 5,
  seperator: '.',
  replacementText: '....'
};

//Given file names to shorten
const files = ['myAwesomeFile.min.css', 'my Awesome File.tar.gz', 'file.png'];

//Function to do the actual file name shortening
const shorten = s =>
  s.length > config.charsBeforeTrim ? `${s.substring(0, config.charsBeforeTrim)}${config.replacementText}` : s;

//Function to generate a short file name with extension(s)
const generateShortName = (file, config) => {
  //ES6 Array destructuring makes it easy to get the file name in a unique variable while keeping the remaining elements (the extensions) in their own array:
  const [name, ...extensions] = file.split(config.seperator);

  //Simply append all remaining extension chunks to the shortName
  return extensions.reduce((accum, extension) => {
    accum += `${config.seperator}${extension}`;
    return accum;
  }, shorten(name));
};

//Demonstrate usage
const shortFileNames = files.map(file => generateShortName(file, config));

console.log(shortFileNames);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const parse = (filename, extIdx = filename.lastIndexOf('.')) => ({
  name: filename.substring(0, extIdx),
  extension: filename.substring(extIdx + 1),
})

const trimFileName = (
  filename, size = 5, fill = '...', 
  file = parse(filename),
  head = file.name.substring(0, size)
) => file.name.length >= size ? `${head}${fill}${file.extension}` : filename

/* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - */

;[
  'myAwesomeFile.min.css', 
  'my.Awesome.File.min.css',
  'my Awesome File.tar.gz',
  'file.png',
].forEach(f => console.log(trimFileName(f)))
```

Comment: What if the file name contains a '.'. Say the file name is `myAwesome.File.css`

Comment: Then 'File.css' is the extension. There is really no good way to guard against bad file names. For example, 'this.is.filename.not.extension.txt' is a valid txt file. I guess I should consider only the last dot as extension separator.

Answer (score 0):

You can fairly straightforwardly pull the your extension condition (easily replaced with a list of valid extensions) and regex pull the last part. Then you just add a check on the filename (starting at the beginning of filename) to trim the result.

```js
  const trim = (string, x) => {
      // We assume that up to last two . delimited substrings of length are the extension
      const extensionRegex = /(?:(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+){0,2})$/g;
      const { index } = extensionRegex.exec(string);
      // No point in trimming since result string would be longer than input
      if (index + 2 < x) {
        return string;
      }
      return string.substr(0, x) + ".." + string.substr(index);
    };

  /* Assert that we keep the extension */
  console.log("cat.tar.gz", trim("cat.tar.gz", 100) == "cat.tar.gz");
  console.log("cat.zip", trim("cat.zip", 100) == "cat.zip");
  /* Assert that we keep x characters before trim */
  console.log("1234567890cat.tar.gz",!trim("1234567890cat.tar.gz",10).includes("cat"));
  console.log("1234567890cat.zip", !trim("1234567890cat.zip", 10).includes("cat"));
```